# How is the way that iphone received data from mysql with APNs?

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, apple-push-notifications

I am newbie for iphone development and wanna know that what is the way that iphone can received the live data , i mean when the data is inserted into mysql database and instantly can receive it on the iphone and update the recently data into the tableview by Apple push notification service.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to sync data with just push notifications if the app is not active. You cannot execute any code when the app is not active.

But there are other ways:

1) When user tap on the push notification banner, your app is launched. You can do the syncing then. This is the most straight forward way to do it, and you will not get into trouble with app reviewers.

2) Newsstand - you can use push notification to send content update to Newsstand. Your app will be woken up in background to download any content update, but you are only allowed to do this once a day. You app needs to support auto-renewable subscription.

3) If you app uses any of the available background modes (e.g. continuous location update) to run in the background, then application delegate's didReceiveRemoteNotification is called when a push is received. You can do syncing here. But you have to have a good reason to use these background modes, not just as a workaround to keep the app active.